# FILTRO DE BUSCA EM OBJETOS COM FILHOS USANDO RECURSIVIDADE JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Tenho um array com objetos e outros arrays dentro com outros objetos.
Necessito fazer um filtro de busca recursivo mas que me retorne apenas o objeto procurado.
Por enquanto apenas consigo retornar o objeto principal inteiro.
Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

```
const a = [
    {
        nome: "Irwyng",
        filhos: [
            {
                nome: "Patrick",
                filhos: [
                    {
                        nome: "Stags",
                        filhos: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        nome: "Klug",
        filhos: [
            {
                nome: "Melo",
                filhos: [
                    {
                        nome: "Pit",
                        filhos: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        nome: "Marcus",
        filhos: [
            {
                nome: "Chris",
                filhos: [
                    {
                        nome: "Pablo",
                        filhos: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
];

const search = "Pab";

const filter = (array, search) => {
  array.filter((obj) => {
    obj.some((o) => console.log(o))
  })
}
filter(a, search);
```

exemplo:
Se o meu "search" for stags, o filter deve retornar apenas o objeto com nome = "stags"